# Solution Using Series Expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In order to solve $y'-y=x^2$ using series expansion, do I take the series expansion of $y$ and $y'$ and subtract them and I should get $x^2$?

Comment: Sure, let $ya_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+\cdots$, differentiate term by term, set $y'-y=x_2$, Set $a_0=c$ and solve for the other $a_i$. The calculation should not be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$y=c+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots.$$ 
Then 
$$y'=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+\cdots.$$
Subtract. The result should be $x^2$. So we want $a_1=c$, and $2a_2=a_1$ and $3a_3-a_2=1$ and $4a_4=a_3$ and $5a_5=a_4$ and so on.

So $a_1=c$, $a_2=c/2$, $a_3=(1/3)(c/2+1)$, $a_4=(1/12)(c/2+1)$, and so on. The terms from $a_3$ on have a nice shape.